# Getting difference between counts of two subqueries

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to determine the score of an entry by finding the difference between the number of upvotes and downvotes it has received in MYSQL by running `SELECT (SELECT COUNT(vote_id) AS vote_up FROM`votes`WHERE vote='UP'),(SELECT COUNT(vote_id) AS vote_down FROM`votes`WHERE vote='DOWN'),(vote_up - vote_down AS vote_score)`. When I try to run this though, it tells me that I do not have proper syntax. What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there a better way to write this?

And finally, what is the ideal way to find the item with the highest and lowest number of votes? Would I just `ORDER BY [above query]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with

```
SELECT some_id
  , SUM(
      CASE
        WHEN vote = 'UP'
        THEN 1
        WHEN vote = 'DOWN'
        THEN -1
        ELSE 0
      END
    ) as vote_score
FROM votes
GROUP BY some_id
```

Note that the better approach is to have +1 or -1 stored in vote, then you can just do:

```
SELECT some_id, SUM(vote) as vote_score
FROM votes
GROUP BY some_id
```

BTW if my formatting looks odd to you, I explained it in http://bentilly.blogspot.com/2011/02/sql-formatting-style.html.

Comment: +1 however you are going to get a error for missing a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Wow, thanks! This worked perfectly. And your post was a good read, although I don't normally deal with queries that are very long...

Comment: @The Scrum Meister: You're right.  Fixed.  My biggest wish for SQL is that if I didn't have a GROUP BY that it would figure out what it should be based on my SELECT...

Answer (score 5):

You can do it by pulling that last clause into a `(SELECT ...)` block as well:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(vote_id) FROM votes WHERE vote='UP') AS vote_up,
    (SELECT COUNT(vote_id) FROM votes WHERE vote='DOWN') AS vote_down,
    (SELECT vote_up - vote_down) AS vote_score
ORDER BY vote_whatever;
```

Note btilly's answer about having  +/- 1 be the upvote / downvote representation.  It makes a lot more sense in this context, and allows for smaller tables, faster comparisons, and use of the `SUM()` function when necessary:

```
SELECT SUM(vote) from votes;
```

Also note:  You'll only get vote_up and vote_down counts using the multiple `(SELECT ...)` method - `SUM(CASE)` will only give you the total.

Comment: Well, I feel foolish for leaving off the initial SELECT for the third query now.

Comment: The only answer which REALLY answers the question in title

Answer (score 1):

Following up on btilly's answer, If you need to know the lowest and highest but do **not** need to know what ID has the highest/lowest:

```
SELECT MIN(score), MAX(score)
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(IF(vote = 'DOWN', -1, vote = 'UP')) AS score
    FROM votes
    GROUP BY ID
)
```

If you do need to know the ID, use the inner query (add the `ID` to the select) with a `ORDER BY score LIMIT 1` to get the lowest and `ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 1` to get the highest. 
note in the case of ties, this will choose only 1 of them.

Comment: Thanks for this! Unfortunately, I need the id of the entry and the values in between.