# Getting the difference of a count on 2 queries in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am totally new to SQL and have managed to get 2 queries to show me the count.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS 'Sold' FROM table_1 WHERE date_sold >= CURRENT_DATE
```

and the same from table_1 but for date_purchased

Now I need to have a single query, using the 2 queries I have already, to show the difference between purchased today and sold today.

So like this...

[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwcUo.png)

So I need a query to give me the difference in the 2 counts

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a relevant and minimal sample data showcasing your requirements, and expected output. Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904741/getting-difference-between-counts-of-two-subqueries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
select 
  (
    SELECT 
      "count"(*) as val1 
    from 
      tab1
  ) - (
    SELECT 
      "count"(*) as val2 
    from 
      tab2
  ) as total_count
```

Source from [Calculate the difference between results of two count(*) queries based on 2 tables in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21701094/calculate-the-difference-between-results-of-two-count-queries-based-on-2-tabl#21701121)